Is it possible to delay a payment by X number of days in stripe?
in stripe is it possible to delay a payment by X number of days? For example, if someone signs up for a new subscription, how do we say, “No charge for 2 weeks” ? This is important because we want people to get credit cards on file before the my team sets up calls but don’t want to charge them until it’s confirmed we are good-to-go.
is it possible to do this via the portal or does it have to be via API?
what are the steps for setting it up via the portal?
I tried using the free trail but I don't want my customer to see/ consider these gap as a free trail.

If you do not want to use free trials, then I think your best option would be to use Subscription Schedules.  Schedules allow you to make create and make changes to Subscriptions in the future.  In fact, starting a Subscription in the future is the very first use case they document.
However, this means the actual Subscription object will not be created until the Subscription is created.  So if you are using the subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret to collect payment method details as they show in their canonical subscriptions integration doc, you won't have a subscription so no Payment Intent.
It sounds like you are saving payment methods ahead of the Subscription anyway so that may not be an issue but if it is you can always use the Setup Intents integration to save and re-use payment methods.

is this done in the portal? Sorry I'm not very tech savvy.

This isn't something you set up in the Customer Portal (or Checkout) but you can do this using the Dashboard.  When you crate a Subscription using the Dashboard it uses a Subscription Schedule behind the scenes.  You can set the billing start date in the future.
